# Constructing an Array for Dataset - Different Start Points?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop, foreach

I have an array of values set up like:

```
$array[0]['Year', 'Value']
```

Where there are 100 or so array's inside of the main array, each with 30 value pairs of 'Year' and 'Value'.  This works great for all of my current applications, until I came upon various graphing libraries that want their data formatted like:

```
[x1, y1, y2, y3 ...], [x2, y1, y2, y3 ...], ...
```

This would be easy if all of my data points started from the same year, but they do not. My arrays all start at different years, and overlap. The problem with this is, that the graphing libraries format requires a 'null' value as a placemarker for that particular series if there is no Y-axis value for that X-point.

Example:  My $array[0] goes from 1900-1930, my $array[1] goes from 1901-1931.  So, the new array need to be [1900, $array[0]['Value']], null] (to indicate that the $array[1] doesn't have a value there, but is still a series on the graph.  Then [1901, $array[0]['Value'], $array[1]['Value']], etc etc.

I've been drawing out diagrams and trying to wrap my head around creating a series of loops to take my old array and convert it... but I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define your y points, for this we need a range. As you are creating your array I would have two variables, `$minYear` and `$maxYear`, then for every entry into the array you check if it's smaller than minYear, or bigger than maxYear, and if so replace the value with this one.

That gives us our min and max, now we need a range. You need to determine how many points between each year you have. To keep things simple I'm going to assume 1 year is one increment on the y axis. However if you have a maximum number of points on the y axis you can use, then you can use the following formulae to work out how many years are between each point:

```
$increment = ($maxYear - $minYear) / $numPointsOnYAxis;
```

That will give you how many years are between each point on the Y Axis. For simplicity you may wish to round that number using the `ceil()` function. It means you won't use every point on the Y axis, but it keeps the maths nice and easy.

Now we have our range you can use foreach loops to go through your data and plot the graph.

```
$space = '';
foreach($array as $num => $a) {
    echo $space . '[x' . $num;
    foreach($a as $year => $value) {
        $y = ceil(($value - $minValue) / $increment); //Work out how many increments up the scale the year needs to be.
        echo ', y' . $y;
    }
    echo ']';
    $space = ', ';
}
```

That should echo out what you are after. Please not that I haven't tested this code.